# Ошибки при размещении сайта asp.net framework на iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis

Я создал простой сайт на asp.net framework, в котором есть стандартная проверка подлинности пользователей, то есть регистрация, но я добавил в нее нужные мне поля и направил ее на бд sql server, а не в локальную бд, как это было раньше.

Сейчас при попытки входа или регистрации почему то во первых выполняется такой вот запрос в адресной строке :

/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%25

И это не весь запрос, там вот так повторяясь идет около 4000 симоволов. а на страничке в опере выпадает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если через минуту обновить страницу, то появляется вот такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел где то на форуме ответ, что надо выполнить следующее

> Для Интернет-информационных услуг (IIS) 6.0 и более поздних, ключи реестра MaxFieldLength и MaxRequestBytes расположены в следующем подключе:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters

Я вроде задал это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но все равно все также.

Вот лог iis сервера:

135 400 - RequestLength -
2020-01-23 04:20:40 ::1%0 12889 ::1%0 443 HTTP/2 GET

/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525

Подскажите, как это исправить? надо как то разрешить длинный такой запрос? или это косяк в коде и запрос не должен быть такого размера? но это стандартная Asp регистрация, созданная автоматически. Помогите, пожалуйста, устранить ошибку

Comment: Вероятнее всего причина в вашем коде. Чтоб разобраться, верните назад работу с локальной БД, вставьте в код логирование, запустите, проверьте что в логах.

Comment: Да уже не так легко это сделать, я в регистрацию добавил новые поля и так далее, хотя ничего кординального вроде не делал

Comment: @Yaroslav, чтобы вот таких проблем не было, научитесь пользоваться системой контроля версий Git. А конкретно ещё в добавок к самому Git установите приложение SmartGit, я удобнее не встречал. На ютубе есть уроки, там канал по JavaScript, вроде он даже так и называется, только ещё ру на конце, так вот там всё очень хорошо объясняется. Не иметь возможности откатить изменения в проекте - это сильно.

Comment: Разрешите анонимный доступ к вашей логин страничке.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас многократно происходит Redirect, о чем и говорит страница в Opera, то есть сервер возвращает код 3xx. Понять причину без кода тяжело. Возможно, где-то в коде при проверке сессии или токена авторизации, возвращается RedirectResult. Из-за этого и возрастает длина запроса. В реестре менять ничего не нужно, проблема - в коде.